# Memory leak in while look

Tags: c, memory-leaks, struct, while-loop

There's memory leak on this code but I can't find it. It reads from line by line and save some returned values. following code is also on `while(1)` loop which reads file and wait for several seconds and read again.

```
  while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    struct matches matched = check_match(line,lgd,grd);
    if (matched.status>=1)//ali 1 ni taarsan
    {
      timelog1[y] = calloc(strlen(matched.timelog),  sizeof(char));
      strcpy(timelog1[y] ,matched.timelog);
      messages1[y] = calloc(strlen(matched.message), sizeof(char));
      strcpy(messages1[y],matched.message);
      y++;
    }
  }
```

Here struct matches

```
struct matches
{
  char *timelog;
  // char *groups[maxgroup];
  const char *message;       //messaguud hadgalana
  int setting;
  int status;    
};
```

And function is:

```
struct matches check_match(char * input,struct log_data lgd,struct group_data grd);
```

And I declared timelog and messages as follows:

```
char **timelog1 = calloc(maxline, sizeof(char*));
char **messages1 = calloc(maxline, sizeof(char*));
```

> maxline=15000

Where am I leaking memory ?

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, I freed as follows after reading from line

```
  for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
  {
    free(timelog1[i]);
    free(messages1[i]);
  }
```

Comment: Perhaps using the spacebar to make the code a bit more readable would help

Comment: Did you free timelog1 and messages1?

Comment: @ace As i mentioned in UPDATE. Is it right ?

Comment: You also need `free(timelog1); free(messages1);` after the `for` loop. You had four `calloc()` calls, two inside a loop and two outside a loop. Hence you should also have four `free()` calls, two inside a loop, and two outside a loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
calloc(strlen(matched.timelog), sizeof(char));
```

`strlen` is not enough, you need room for the null terminator, you want to allocate `strlen(matched.timelog) + 1`. Same in the other `calloc` calls.

Comment: When I read the code it seems the allocated memory is not being freed that is the reason for memory leak right?

Comment: @Gopi the code that is pasted cannot let us determine if the memory is freed or not.

Comment: Yes sir I feel that might be causing the memory leak , your answer corrects the allocation part which is good but since the question talks about memory leak I can't relate your answer to that part